# What is #import and @class for and why are they in both the .h and .m files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Why do you need to use import statements in the .h and .m files

What is the difference between @class Possession and #import Possession.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do you need to use import statements in the .h and .m files

You don't necessarily need to duplicate import statements in both the `.h` and `.m` files. If you `#import` a file in a `.h` file, and then import *that* `.h` file in your `.m` file, then anything imported in the `.h` will be available in the `.m` file.

> What is the difference between @class Possession and #import Possession.h

`@class` *declares* a class, but it doesn't define it; it's just a say to say, "A class called `Possession` exists somewhere in the project." It's used if you only need to declare a type, but you don't need to access any variables or methods in the class.

A `#import` statement just imports a header file.